# ArrayFormula, Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

This seems to be a simple problem that I cannot get around. I have the following formula (works fine).

```
=MEDIAN(FILTER('Filtered-Data'!$D$4:$D,'Filtered-Data'!$C$4:$C=B3))
```

What I want is to use ArrayFormula to get a column wise result for the range B3:B instead of just B3

Can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

First idea was to use Google QUERY function, however it does not support standard SQL `SELECT ... WHERE... IN (valA,valB...)` clause. However thing you want is achievable with `ARRAYFORMULA`. The trick is to match appropriately two columns, handle errors, and apply appropriate filtering (multiline for readability):

```
=MEDIAN(FILTER(Filtered-Data'!$D$4:$D,
  ARRAYFORMULA(IF(IFERROR(MATCH
   (Filtered-Data'!$D$4:$D,'Filtered-Data'!$C$4:$C=B3:B,0),0)>0,TRUE,FALSE))))
```

Explanation:

1. `ARRAYFORMULA(MATCH(col1,col2,0))` finds in array first row containing value matching criteria, 0/1 determines whether matching starts from top or bottom. For standalone use, `MATCH` stops after producing first result. Applying `ARRAYFORMULA` on `MATCH` gets us close to what we want - it produces an array of results. However, if item is not matched, error is returned, so you get something like below, in a column:

   ```
   N/A 
   2
   3
   1
   3
   2
   N/A
   N/A
   N/A
   1
   3
   ```
2. These `N/A` stuff will do us no good, since we always want some kind of row number. Here comes `IFERROR`, which replaces all `N\A` with good ol' "0": `IFERROR(MATCH(col1,col2,0),0)`
   Google Spreadsheet never counts rows from "0" (it starts from "1", only offsets are zero-based), so this is pretty safe unless your data contains "0" - than change it to anything else safe for your case.
3. Since FILTER expects in filtering_criteria single column array of booleans or expression that evaluates to array of booleans (https://support.google.com/drive/table/25273?hl=en ) we need to make sure `ARRAYFORMULA` produces such array of booleans. `IF` comes in handy - always produces either TRUE or FALSE: `IF(IFERROR(MATCH(col1,col2,0)>0,TRUE,FALSE)`
4. Now re-apply ARRAYFORMULA on that stuff, to work on array & render an array result instead of single result: `ARRAYFORMULA(IF(IFERROR(MATCH(col1,col2,0)>0,TRUE,FALSE))` and put it inside `FILTER`... voila, it works.

For reference see: http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/PpnZinkLzQs